# Performance issue on complex WPF application, how to solve that?

Tags: wpf, performance, refresh, rate

I have my main window at something like 6000 x 6000 px. In that window, I can have a lot of controls (more than 5000) and we can zoom/pan where we want.

I added 10 "television screens" controls in my application, and each of them have a refresh rate of 100ms.
When I start this, everything crash...

10 objects with a refresh rate of 100ms each is too much, WPF cannot draw them at the time. I conclude that WPF is very slow to draw what I have....

Everything is drawn in vector, but I tried to add .CacheMode on them and it doesn't work either..

What can I do?

P.S. My PC is 8 core, 8 GB Ram, 256 Mb video card (nvidia quadro nvs 295) on win7 64bits

Comment: You have > 5000 controls in a 6000x6000 window and you conclude that WPF is slow? That's like me writing a horrendous sorting algorithm in C and concluding that C is slow.

Comment: A 6000x6000 window @32-bit colour might use over half of your video memory.  If you're doing insane things, you should at least have a half-decent (1GB) graphics card.  Do you mean a refresh rate of 100ms, i.e. 10FPS, or 100 FPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work on reducing the number of controls in your application. 5K is quite a bit, and I think there is probably a way to reduce that number.

For example, use `TextBlocks` instead of `Labels` as TextBlocks render as 1 control while Labels render as 3 in 4.0 (I think its more than 3 in older versions)

Also, check and see if you can use UI Virtualization with some of your controls. Something like a `ListBox` of 100 items can be virtualized to only render 10 of them at a time.

Answer (score 3):

WPF uses software rendering in case you exceed maximum supported resolution of you graphics adapter. Moreover, 5k controls! Incredible. WPF is not a silver bullet for everything you imagine. You need to redesign your app or change technology you're using.

Comment: We cannot change technology, we need to find solution, and we know that no one did want we want

Comment: There are plenty of alternative technologies that will do what you want a lot better.  It just won't be easy.  Something using an actual performance graphics API (OpenGL,Direct3D) would do the trick just fine.  WPF would not and should not have been used in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [ZoomableCanvas - 1 million items](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaelr/archive/2010/08/11/zoomableapplication2-a-million-items.aspx). This is the best example out there of what WPF can do when using every optimisation in the book. I suggest you take that example and run it at the maximum resolution on your monitors. If that fails to perform well, then WPF cannot do this.

I was unaware that WPF default to software rendering if the resolution exceeds that of the video card. A good caveat to know about!

Regarding high performance graphical APIs I second [Keiren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376409/kieren-johnstone) and say use DirectX ([SlimDX](http://slimdx.org/) provides a managed wrapper) instead.